# How to modify XML and XSLT for a collection of values?

Tags: xml, xslt, collections

Below is the data I am getting:

```
<AddressIDs>
                    <AddressID IDType="ABC_1">
                        <HNumber>YYY_1</HNumber>
                    </AddressID>
                    <AddressID IDType="ABC_2">
                        <HNumber>YYY_2</HNumber>
                    </AddressID>
                    <AddressID IDType="ABC_3">
                        <HNumber>YYY_3</HNumber>
                    </AddressID>
                    <AddressID IDType="ABC_4">
                        <HNumber>YYY_4</HNumber>
                    </AddressID>
                </AddressIDs>
```

I have to display on my page something like this, HNumber:YY_1|YYY_2|YYY_3|YYY_4.

This is how I have written my XML and XSLT:

XML:

```
<AddressID Label="HNumber:" XPath="AddressIDs/AddressID" IDType="ABC_*">
    <HNumber XPath="AddressIDs/AddressID/HNumber"></HNumber>
  </AddressID>
```

XSLT:

```
<label>HNumber:</label>
          <label>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="AddressIDs/AddressID [contains(@IDType,'ABC_')]!=''">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(AddressIDs/AddressID [contains(@IDType,'ABC_')]/HNumber,'|')"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </label>
```

Please suggest if this is correct.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? are you getting error? what doesn't work?

Comment: It gives me only the first value which is YYY_1 and because I am concatenating a pipe, the final output is YYY_1|. But I want an output of YYY_1|YYY_2|YYY_3|YYY_4. I think the XSLT needs to have a for or foreach loop but I am not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

The `concat` function concatenates strings together. If one of the arguments is an xpath expression, it will use the value of the first node returned by that expression.

If you are using XSLT 1.0, one solution is to use an `xsl:for-each` to select all the nodes, and build up the string that way. For example

```
<xsl:for-each select="AddressIDs/AddressID [starts-with(@IDType,'ABC_')]/HNumber">
   <xsl:if test="position() > 1">|</xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, if you are using XSLT 2.0, you can make use of the `separator` attribute on `xsl:value-of`, like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="AddressIDs/AddressID [starts-with(@IDType,'ABC_')]/HNumber" separator="|" />
```